# TensorFlow estimator to run evaluation and prediction every N training steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am happily using the `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` to train and evaluate a model. Now, I would like to have a bit more control over the whole thing and more precisely, I would like to:

- save a checkpoint every `N` steps
- run the evaluation over the checkpoint (maybe also on different data sets);
- run the prediction and dump the results in a human-readable form on the same checkpoint.

Is there any easy (possibly off-the-shelf) way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: For saving checkpoint, you would need to pass a config object when you create the estimator. Take a look at [RunConfig](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig) for more details. 
For the second point, the frequency of evaluation is controlled by throttle_secs in [EvalSpec](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EvalSpec). You can set that according to when you checkpoint. From what I can infer from the docs, you load the checkpoint and then evaluate by default, as the evalspec creates a separate graph but that is something we need to confirm!